# Hadith authenticity regarding rafidah (Sunni View Only)

Tags: source-identification, shiism

Its been seen that following hadith are being quoted in forums, its not possible for me to verify the references, hence I require the source link for the following hadith linked to an actual hadith site for verification:

### First hadith:

> ((وعن فاطمة رضی اللّٰہ عنہا بنت محمدصلی اللّٰہ علیہ وسلم قالت نظر النبی صلی اللّٰہ علیہ وسلم الی علی فقال ھذا فی الجنة ،وان من شیعتہ یعلمون (وفی روایة یلفظون)الاسلام ثم یرفضونہ، لھم نبزیسمون(وفی روایةیشھدون)) الرافضة من لقیھم فلیقتلھم فانھم مشرکون))

Source: (مسند ابی یعلیٰ ۱۳،۴۹۱،رقم:۶۶۰۵۔راوہ الطبرانی ورجالہ ثقات بحوالہ مجمع الزوائد،ج:۱۰،ص:۲۲)

**Translation:**

> Fatimah r.a. bint Muhammad s.a.w. said: "The Prophet s.a.w. looked towards `Ali (r.a.) then said: "He will be in Jannah, and indeed from his party will be such knowing (and in a narration "pronouncing") Islam then they will reject it, for them is destruction, they will be named "RaafiDah", whoever encounters them then he should kill them for indeed they will be mushrikoon.

Source:(Musnad Abu Ya`la: #6605, narrated by at-Tabaraani and its Rijaal are Thiqaat=> Majma` az-Zawaaid: vol.10, pg.22)

---

### Second Hadith:

> ((وعن ابن عباس رضی اللّٰہ عنہ قال کنت مع النبی صلی اللّٰہ علیہ وسلم وعندہ علی فقال النبی صلی اللّٰہ علیہ وسلم،یاعلی!سیکون فی امتی قوم ینتحلون حب اھل البیت لھم نبز یسمون الرافضة قا تلوھم فانھم مشرکون))

Source: (رواہ الطبرانی واسنادہ حسن بحوالة مجمع الزوائد،ج:۱۰،ص:۲۲۔السنةلاب ن ابی عاصم،ج:۲،ص:۴۷۶)

**Translation:**

> Ibn `Abbas r.a. said: "I was with the Prophet s.a.w. and` Ali (r.a.) was near him so the Prophet s.a.w. said: "O `Ali! Soon there will be in my Ummah a people pretending to love Ahl al-Bayt, for them is destruction, they will be named "RaafiDah", fight them for indeed they will be mushrikoon"

Source: (Narrated by at-Tabaraani and its Isnaad is Hasan=> Majma` az-Zawaaid: vol.10,pg.22, as-Sunnah li-Ibn Abi `AaSim: vol.2,pg.476)

---

### Also similar narrations:

> Ibrahim reported that his father Hasan said that his father Hasan said that his father Ali bin Abu-Talib (may Allah be pleased with them) said: "The Messenge of Allah said: There will appear, at the end of time, people who are called Rawafidah (rejecters). They will reject Islam." [Musnad Ahmad]
>
> Abdullah ibn Abbaas (may Allah be pleased with them) reported that The Messenger (may peace be upon him) said: "There will be, at the end of the time, people who are called Rawafid (rejecters). They will reject Islam and spit it out. Thus, KILL THEM for they are polytheist."

**Note**: *if you are unable to provide link then even scanned pages is OK as I don't have these books. And if you have any comments then please clarify rather than Downvoting.*

Comment: Can you provide the isnad please.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the first and second narrations have the same origin.  The *isnad* from *Musnad Abu Y'ala* is =

> حَدَّثَنَا زُهَيْرٌ، حَدَّثَنَا هَاشِمٌ، حَدَّثَنَا عِمْرَانُ بْنُ
>
> زَيْدٍ التَّغْلِبِيُّ، حَدَّثَنِي الْحَجَّاجُ بْنُ تَمِيمٍ، عَنْ
>
> مَيْمُونِ بْنِ مِهْرَانَ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، عَنِ
>
> النَّبِيِّ

It is **weak.**

**عمران بن زيد الثعلبي** was not a reliable person.  Ibn al-Jowzi mentioned him in *ad-Do'afaa'*

**الحجاج بن تميم الجزري** was daif.  Imam an-Nasai said he was not *thiqa*.

He was declared as weak in *Taqrib*.

Abu Jafar al-Aqili said not to follow his narrations from Maimun bin Mihran.  And this is narrated from him.

The *isnad* for the third *hadith* from *Musnad Ahmed* is also **weak**=

> حَدَّثَنَا عَبْد اللَّهِ، حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ جَعْفَرٍ
>
> الْوَرَكَانِيُّ فِي سَنَةِ سَبْعٍ وَعِشْرِينَ وَمِائَتَيْنِ،
>
> حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو عَقِيلٍ يَحْيَى بْنُ الْمُتَوَكِّلِ، حَدَّثَنَا
>
> مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ سُلَيْمَانَ لُوَيْنٌ فِي سَنَةِ أَرْبَعِينَ
>
> وَمِائَتَيْنِ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو عَقِيلٍ يَحْيَى بْنُ الْمُتَوَكِّلِ،
>
> عَنْ كَثِيرٍ النَّوَّاءِ، عَنْ إِبْرَاهِيمَ بْنِ حَسَنِ بْنِ حَسَنِ
>
> بْنِ عَلِيِّ بْنِ أَبِي طَالِبٍ رَضِيَ اللَّهُ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ
>
> جَدِّهِ، قَالَ: قَالَ عَلِيُّ بْنُ أَبِي طَالِبٍ رَضِيَ اللَّهُ
>
> عَنْهُ: قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ

**يحيى بن المتوكل الضرير** He was declared weak by many scholars  like Ali al-Madani, Yahya bin Main, an-Nasai, Darimi, Abu Jafar al-Aqili, ibn Abdul Bar

** كَثِيرٍ النَّوَّاءِ** he was also declared as weak by Imam an-Nasai and Abu Hatim ar-Razi.

**إبراهيم بن الحسن الهاشمي** he too is weak and a *mudallis*.  (ad-do'afaa).

**الحسن بن الحسن الهاشمي** no scholar said he was *thiqa*

Hence, *hadith* is unreliable.

The fourth narration's *isnad* is =

> حَدَّثَنَا زُهَيْرٌ، حَدَّثَنَا هَاشِمٌ، حَدَّثَنَا عِمْرَانُ بْنُ
>
> زَيْدٍ التَّغْلِبِيُّ، حَدَّثَنِي الْحَجَّاجُ بْنُ تَمِيمٍ، عَنْ
>
> مَيْمُونِ بْنِ مِهْرَانَ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، عَنِ
>
> النَّبِيّ

It's the same *isnad* as the first two *ahadith* and the weakness is similar.

So all four of these narrations are unauthentic and not reliable.

waAllaho Alim.

Comment: Thanks, but does that make the hadith weak or inauthentic?. Moreover in that text it is mentioned that isnad is thiqat, there are some other scholars which consider the Isnad to be thiqa . So at worst the hadith can be daeef not inauthentic(fabricated). Also can you link to evidences where the scholars said that a person in the chain is weak?